# Domain of analyticity, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm stuck with this question:

Determine the domain of analyticity of $$f(z)=\log(4+i-z).$$ How do I proceed from there? Is there an easy pattern to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the branch you choose for the logarithm. For example, I will assume that you use the principal branch, that is to say that your logarithm is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0].$ (The principal branch is that you fix the argument to take value in $(-\pi,\pi]$.)

Now you can ask the question : When does $4+i-z$ belongs to $(-\infty,0]$ ? It is equivalent to say that $z \in i+[4,+\infty)$. So it is equivalent to $x\geq4$ and $y=1$. From that you can conclude that your function is holomorphic on $$\mathbb{C}\backslash \{(x,y): x\geq 4, y=1\}.$$ You can moreover prove that this is the biggest domain of holomorphy since the function is not continuous on the half-line $\{(x,y): x\geq 4, y=1\}.$

Comment: I just noticed I wrote wrong, it's supposed to be log(4+i-z). Can you just describe two things, what does it mean that I use the "principal branch"?

Comment: The answer is supposed to x>=4, y=1, if y=1, that would mean that the imaginary parts would take themselves out, is that a neccesary condition?

Comment: I added some details

Comment: ahh, okay, I think I understand, thanks for the help! Can you just tell me one last thing, when I say that I fix my argument to take value in (-pi,pi], what does that really mean for my function?